# search lines in bash for specific character and display line

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to write search a string in `bash` and `echo` the line of that string that contains the `+` character with some text `is a special case`. The code does run but I get both lines in the input file displayed.  Thank you :)

**bash**

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Please enter the variant the following are examples"
echo " c.274G>T or c.274-10G>A"

printf "variant(s), use a comma between multiple: "; IFS="," read -a variant

for ((i=0; i<${#variant[@]}; i++))
 do printf "NM_000163.4:%s\n" ${variant[$i]} >> c:/Users/cmccabe/Desktop/Python27/input.txt
done
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/+/)print $i}' input.txt
echo "$i" "is a  special case"
```

**input.txt**

```
NM_000163.4:c.138C>A
NM_000163.4:c.266+83G>T
```

**desired output** ( this line contains a `+` in it)

```
NM_000163.4:c.266+83G>T is a special case
```

edit:

looks like I need to `escape the +` and that is part of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your awk script as below and get rid of echo.

```
$ awk '/+/{print $0,"is a special case"}' file
```

NM_000163.4:c.266+83G>T is a special case

Comment: Thank you both very much :).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem, you can do it with a single sed command:

```
sed -n '/+/ {s/$/is a special case/ ; p}' input.txt
```

On lines containing `+`, it replaces the end (`$`) with your text, thus appending it. After that the line is printed.